# fns[i](socket, function(err){ TypeError: Property '0' of object [object Object] is not a function in /socket.io/lib/namespace.js:119

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am new to socket.io and node.js I refered some online documents and created a socket server, it was working fine, but now it shows so many errors, Since I don't know socket.io and node.js I am unable to rectify the problem.

I am receiving the following error in my server side

> /home/sitename/public_html/chat-server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:119
>       fns[i](socket, function(err){
>             ^ TypeError: Property '0' of object [object Object] is not a function
>       at run (/home/sitename/public_html/chat-server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:119:11)
>       at Namespace.run (/home/sitename/public_html/chat-server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:131:3)
>       at Namespace.add (/home/sitename/public_html/chat-server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:160:8)
>       at Client.connect (/home/sitename/public_html/chat-server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:76:20)
>       at Server.onconnection (/home/sitename/public_html/chat-server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:367:10)
>       at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at Server.handshake (/home/sitename/public_html/chat-server/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:310:8)
>       at Server.onWebSocket (/home/sitename/public_html/chat-server/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:392:10)
>       at /home/sitename/public_html/chat-server/node_modules/engine.io/lib/server.js:335:12
>       at completeHybiUpgrade2 (/home/sitename/public_html/chat-server/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js:284:5)

and in the client side I am receiving the following error

> GET
>   https://sitename/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1483766845342-50

and

> WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://sitename:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed:
>   Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

client side code

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.2.js"></script>

  var socket = io();

    var socket = io.connect( 'https://sitename:3000',{secure: true,
'sync disconnect on unload': true,'reconnect': true,
  'reconnection delay': 500, rejectUnauthorized: false ,   transports: [
    'websocket', 
    'flashsocket', 
    'htmlfile', 
    'xhr-polling', 
    'jsonp-polling', 
    'polling'
  ]} );
```

server side code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var app = require('express')();
var https = require('https');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./privatekey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./certificate.crt')
};
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
//var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var socket = io.use({
  transports: [
    'websocket', 
    'flashsocket', 
    'htmlfile', 
    'xhr-polling', 
    'jsonp-polling', 
    'polling'
  ]
});



var clients=[];
var gamename={};
var socketid={};


app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://sitename:3000');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

});

server.listen(3000, function(){

  console.log('It is Listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: I would hazard a guess that one of your transports is not valid.  You could try removing them all except for `websocket` and see if you learn anything.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for your time. Do I have to add it in server side or client side ?

Comment: @jfriend00 still the same problem in the server

Comment: I'd say remove all transports entirely from both client and server so you have a default implementation (which should just be websocket and xhr-polling) and see if the problem is still there.  Why are you adding so many transports?  And, what are the `htmlfile` and `polling` transports?  You can't just make up transport names that are not supported in your implementation.

Comment: @jfriend00  thanks bro, I will try it.

Comment: @@jfriend00  Thank you 1000000 times bro , it worked, if you add it as answer I will accept it as correct answer and upvote it ............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you probably have invalid transports specified which causes socket.io to make an error (I don't recognize transport names like `htmlfile` and `polling`).

The way you know if this is the case or not is to remove all transports entirely from both client and server so you don't even specify that option.  Then you will have only the default, built-in transports (which should just be just websocket and xhr-polling).

You must only specify transports that you have support for and that you actually  need.  You cannot just make up transport names.

Comment: I am not able to upvote, it changes to zero automatically

Comment: @scriptkiddie1 - You need a reputation of 15 in order to upvote.  You can see the list of privileges and how many reputation points they take [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) and you can see how much reputation you earn for various activities [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).  It looks like you just earned 7 points, 5 for an upvote on your question and 2 for accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
```

You should pass object "{ transports: [] }" into .listen func as below:

```
let io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {
    transports: ['websocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'polling']
});
```

into use() you can pass cb func as below:

```
io.use(async (socket, next) => {
    const {
        handshake: {
            query
        }
    } = socket;
    if (query && .query.token){
        jwt.verify(query.token, 'SECRET_KEY', function(err, decoded){
          if(err) return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
          socket.decoded = decoded;
          next();
       });
    } else {
      next(new Error('Authentication error'));
    }    
})
 .on('connection', (socket) => {
    // emit ot listen socket
    socket.on('message', (message) => {
       console.log('=================== ', message);
 })
});
```